# BeautifulSoup get an attribute from a find

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm very new to python so first of all sorry, i want to print href content from a selection made with find() method from beautifulsoup but i cannot do that and i don't know why. i've do this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import session

payload = {
    'btnSubmit': 'Login',
    'username': 'xxx',
    'password': 'xxx'
   }

 with session() as c:
     c.post('http://www.xxx.xxx/login.php', data=payload)
     request = c.get('http://www.xxx.xxx/xxxx')
     soup=BeautifulSoup(request.content)
     row_int=soup.find('td',attrs={'class' : 'rnr-cc rnr-bc rnr-icons'})
     print row_int['href']
```

but i've this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
execfile ('C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\prova.py')
File "C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\prova.py", line 15, in <module>
print row_int['href']
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 905, in __getitem__
return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

the content of row_int is like this:

```
[<a class="rnr-button-img" data-icon="view" href="xxxxxxx" id="viewLink12" name="viewLink12" title="Details"></a>, u' ']
```

where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the links (`a` elements) from inside the `td` tags:

```
row = soup.find('td', attrs={'class': 'rnr-cc rnr-bc rnr-icons'})
a = row.find('a', href=True)
if a:
    print a['href']
```

Or, shorter with a [`CSS selector`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for a in soup.select('td.rnr-cc.rnr-bc.rnr-icons a[href]'):
    print a['href']
```